# Recyclerview does not scroll below collapsing appbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement a recyclerview below a appbarlayout, so that the recyclerview collapses together with the appbar. It works so far but unfortunately the recyclerview does not scroll anymore.

Could somebody please help me? I searched for some examples on stackoverflow but unfortunatly I can`t get it to work.

Here is the related xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dropDownVerticalOffset="@dimen/dropDownVerticalOffset"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Initializing.."
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/ToolBarTitle"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteAccent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#191512"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#191512"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the code below?

You put the `RecyclerView` inside the AppBarLayout, and below is put it out of AppBarLayout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dropDownVerticalOffset="@dimen/dropDownVerticalOffset"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Initializing.."
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/ToolBarTitle"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteAccent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />



    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<!-- put it out of AppBarLayout -->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#191512"

/>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#191512"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Liu, thx for reacting, unfortunately it doesn`t work, the recyclerview is not visible anymore.

Comment: @Simon can you try to remove `RelativeLayout ` below the `RecyclerView`? Actually I reproduced your issue and resolved it just now :)

Comment: what do you mean? Where comes the imageview then? You have your .xml?

Comment: Not sure I understand you, you have `RelativeLayout / ImageView` in your xml.

Comment: Hi Liu, you were right, I needed to remove the RelativeLayout.
Thx for your help.